# htaccess redirect third level domain on the main one

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have to solve this simple situation. I have a bunch of third level domain like: `oldthirdlevel.example.com` that I want to redirect on the main domain that is `www.example.com`. I've tried with a simple 301 redirect on the file `.htaccess` but without any success. I would like to redirect every kind of path to the home of main domain for example:

```
oldthirdlevel.example.com/whatever --> www.example.com
oldthirdlevel.example.com/otherthings --> www.example.com
```

this is my file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldthirdlevel.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But I got a 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: in your example you do not mention to  add the old path to the main-domain url .: only www.example.com. Second: you're missing the www in the rewriterule (not that that should lead to a 500 error, but still

Comment: if it is about "a bunch". would it be an option to say: when not domain equals www.example.com:  
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domeinnaam\.tld$` `RewriteRule ^.*$         http://www.domeinnaam.tld/$0    [R=301,L]`

Comment: @IvoP Maybe I forgot an important thing. All these third level domain has separate hosting. I'm a bit confused right now, I had to change the .htaccess on the third level domains or in the main domain server? The main domain is working with a dedicate server, third levels domains has separate hosting providers.

Comment: your browser will try to access oldthirdlevel.example.com. It will not know better then to look for it on the old hosting. There you need a .htaccess file with rewriterule to redirect the visiting browser to the new location (on the www.hosting)

Comment: Consider having all these subdomains in one hosting surrounding. You could even use the same docroot as the www. You will need to tell Apache in a vhost file. And you need to change the dns settings for the subdomain

Comment: Ok what if the third levels has apache server and the main one nginx? I know it's a mess.

Comment: sorry: i don't know about rewriteing rules in Nginx.

Comment: but for the sub hosting: is Apache setup so it knows how to handle rewrite rules?

Comment: Ok it is working. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: if you want to post as answer I will mark as correct. Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it is about "a bunch". would it be an option to say: when not domain equals www.example.com:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.tld$ 
 RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.example.tld/$0 [R=301,L]
```